# VirtualBox: Guest Additions Install Fail

Tags: virtualbox, amd-ryzen, guest-additions

I have a problem while trying to install the Ubuntu Guest Additions on my virtual machine on Virtual Box. I run in the terminal the following commands

```
sudo apt update
```

and then

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

I've chosen from devices Insert Guest Additions CD image and then I went to the `autorun.sh` file and chose the "Run as a program" option. At this point, I got an error that something went wrong and then the screen started to look like this

[Error visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chmA8.jpg)

I have a Lenovo AMD RYZEN 7 7840 HS and I've also encountered a problem at the beginning of the Ubuntu installation but I fixed that by running on the Windows Command Prompt the commands:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/CPUM/HostCPUID/80000006/edx" "0x00009040"
```

I don't know if the issue can be related to that.